# AbstractMethodError while creating JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, maven

I've been trying to set up application using Spring Boot, Hibernate and PostgreSQL. But I keep getting `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException`.

Thats the trace I'm getting.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: : Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receivedRequestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receivedRequestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:209) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:146) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:74) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:234) [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221) [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84) [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.my.company.worker.config;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Created by on 2015-10-01.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.my.company.worker.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.company.worker.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseBeans {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseBeans.class);

    @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;
    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Bean
    public DataSource basicDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
        basicDataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
        basicDataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        basicDataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

        return basicDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("PostgreSQL");
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(basicDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.my.company.worker.dao");

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(basicDataSource());

        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
package com.my.company.worker.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.my.company.worker.model.ReceivedRequest;

/**
 * Created by  on 2015-10-01.
 */
@Repository
public interface ReceivedRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<ReceivedRequest, Integer> {
    ReceivedRequest findById(Integer id);
}
```

My entity:

```
package com.my.company.worker.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
/**
 * Created by  on 2015-10-01.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECEIVED_REQUEST")
public class ReceivedRequest {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    //@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "request_content")
    String content;

    @Column(name = "received_time")
    Timestamp timestamp;

    @Column(name = "status")
    String status;

    public ReceivedRequest(String content, Timestamp timestamp, String status) {
        this.content = content;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "[id: "+id+", content: "+content+", time: "+timestamp+", status: "+"]";
    }
}
```

and finally pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.my.company.worker</groupId>
  <artifactId>noc-worker</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>noc-worker</name>
  <description>Project for job service implementing changes from NOC.</description>

  <properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.ekryd.sortpom</groupId>
        <artifactId>sortpom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <createBackupFile>false</createBackupFile>
          <predefinedSortOrder>custom_1</predefinedSortOrder>
          <lineSeparator>\n</lineSeparator>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
          <sortProperties>true</sortProperties>
          <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
          <sortDependencies>scope</sortDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I got this right. Turns out that my `spring-orm` version was higher than my `spring-core` and it caused problems described in my question. After setting `spring-orm` version to that of a `spring-core` everything started to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The truth lies in the stack trace :)

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: : Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path

I don't think you've added the proper maven dependencies for [FasterXML Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added dependencies as you suggested but it didn't help, although I think that the problem lies somwhere in here. I may have some conflicting dependencies or lack some of them. My reasoning is that when inspecting dependency tree I found that `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` is inside `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Interface don't need `@Repository` annotation, remove this annotation and restart your application.

Comment: I believe that it won't get autowired if I drop the @Repository annotation.

Comment: No you'll get it because you have already: `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.company.worker.dao")`  and this `entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.my.company.worker.dao");`